# How to programmatically get Flash version including build number

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to programmatically detect the version of Flash installed in the browser, using Javascript.

I know about swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion(), but it only returns the major.minor.release parts of the Flash version, and I need the build number (e.g. M.m.r.build) as well.

There seems to be a way to get at the build number in ActionScript, but I need to do this from Javascript, so I can pass the value back to the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a tiny Flash movie on the page?  If so, you could use the Actionscript method and relay the information to javascript via `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Don't know any Actionscript -- so this would have to be only as a last resort...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the [JavaScript Flash Detection Library](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html) and it appears to return the full version with build number. You would just need to parse the returned string. 
Function `FlashDetect.raw` appears to be the function.

Comment: The documentation does imply that the FlashDetect.raw call does this:"This property is used to retrieve the ActiveX object variable $version (e.g., WIN 9,0,28,0) of the installed Flash Player for Windows Internet Explorer or the enabledPlugin.description property for all other browsers." --- but it is not true. I tried it in FF, IE11 and Chrome, and it still only reports the major, minor, release, not the build number :-(