# How to make swfobject or another script show Flash Player's build number with javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

From the [SWFObject documentation](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api):

> swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion() Returns a JavaScript object
>   containing the major version (major:Number), minor version
>   (minor:Number) and release version (release:Number) of an installed
>   Flash player. Please note that while **Flash version numbers normally
>   consist of major.minor.release.build, SWFObject only looks at the
>   first 3 numbers**, so both "WIN 9,0,18,0" (IE) or "Shockwave Flash 9
>   r18" (all other browsers) will translate to "9.0.18".

So what if I do want to know the buildnumber as well?
For example: I want to have "18,0,0,209" instead of just "18,0,0"

The solutions that were discussed [here](http://pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Flash/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25752216/5134583) did not show accurate results at all for me.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31432248/2256820) ?